# InfoPath Development IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, infopath-2007

I need some guidance on creating a "proper" development environment for InfoPath. Here's what I have:

1 - An existing InfoPath form template with a significant amount of code that, thus far, I've been editing with the basic MS script editor

2 - InfoPath 2007

3 - Visual Studio 2010

I can't find anything obvious in VS that would indicate the ability to develop Infopath forms - I only find entries for InfoPath add-ins.

How can I combine these tools so that I can develop my InfoPath code within VS?

Comment: I should clarify that my current InfoPath forms use javascript for the code behind (inherited projects!)

Answer (score 1):

I develop InfoPath forms too, and I sympathize with you and the desire to work in Visual Studio. MSE is pretty bare bones for anybody who's used to VS 2008, 2010 or 2012, and it's chafing to work in that environment.

When developing code for InfoPath forms, you have the choice of either MSE or Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA), but I believe VSTA supports managed languages only (C#/ VB).

The only way you can get to Visual Studio from where you are now is to make a switch from javascript to .net.

reference: [About InfoPath Programming Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb250982%28v=office.12%29.aspx)